# HOUR() returning NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null

I am trying to execute this query on MYSQL 5.5.34

```
SELECT `CustomerName`,`BookingDate`, HOUR(`BookingDate`)from bookings;
```

which results in NULL,

but same query is working correctly in MYSQL 5.5.16 and returns Hours of particular date

Any help or Thoughts of bug reporting about MYSQL 5.5.34

Comment: may you try `HOUR(cast('BookingDate' as datetime))`

Comment: Possible datatype error.

Comment: could not cast to dateTime format, it also returns Null....
my date time format is '2013-9-30 17:10:169-300'

Comment: @NaumanRafique Your datetime format is incorrect. What does `169-300` part represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datetime format is **incorrect**. It's unclear what `169-300` part represents...

But you can extract an hour part even from partially correct format by using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) first

```sql
SELECT CustomerName,
       BookingDate, 
       HOUR(STR_TO_DATE(BookingDate, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i')) hour
  FROM bookings;
```

Output:

```
| CUSTOMERNAME |             BOOKINGDATE | HOUR |
|--------------|-------------------------|------|
|    Customer1 | 2013-9-30 17:10:169-300 |   17 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ca6fd/3)** demo *(MySQL 5.1.61)*

Answer (score 1):

`HOUR()` function in MySQL has an argument of **time** datatype. If you want to get the time from a datetime format, you should use `EXTRACT()` like:

```
-- SYNTAX: EXTRACT(unit FROM date)
SELECT `CustomerName`,`BookingDate`, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(`BookingDate` as datetime)) from bookings;
```

Reference:

- [Date and Time
  Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: What is the datatype of your BookingDate?

Comment: varchar... its giving correct result in MySQL 5.5.16 with same datatype

Comment: Even if you have a datetime format, still you have to use `EXTRACT()`